# Jquery function for dynamic tag creation not working?

Tags: html, jquery

After selecting the files with this,

```
<input type="file" id="myfile1" name="myfile1" data-preview="preview1"
       onchange="readURL(this);" accept="image/*" multiple />
```

read method should dynamically create the `img` tag and view the image uploaded,

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files.length > 0) {
    var index, reader3, file;

    for (index = 0; index < input.files.length; index++) {
      file = input.files[index];
      console.log(file);
      if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
        if (window.FileReader) {
          reader3 = new FileReader();
          reader3.onloadend = function (e) {
            $('#floor_plan_preview').append(
              '' +
                '<div class="col-12 ubw-outer">' +
                '<div class="upload-btn-wrapper">' +
                '<button class="btn" style="pointer-events: none;">' +
                '<img src="" alt=""></button>' +
                '<img alt="" id="preview' +
                (index) +
                '" class="preview"></div></div>'
            );
            $('#preview' + (index)).attr('src', e.target.result);
          };
          reader3.readAsDataURL(file);
          console.log(index);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this loops through files array as expected but only renders the `img` tag with same id at every time.

It seems `reader3.onloadend` function runs only once how can i fix this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that when `onloaded` callback is executed, the value of index will always be the last one in the loop. To fix that you can wrap the callback into IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression):

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files.length > 0) {
    var index, reader3, file;

    for (index = 0; index < input.files.length; index++) {

      file = input.files[index];
      if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
        if (window.FileReader) {
          reader3 = new FileReader();
          (function(index) { // wrap the callback into IIFE
            reader3.onloadend = function(e) {
              $('#floor_plan_preview').append(
                '' +
                '<div class="col-12 ubw-outer">' +
                '<div class="upload-btn-wrapper">' +
                '<button class="btn" style="pointer-events: none;">' +
                '<img src="" alt=""></button>' +
                '<img alt="" id="preview' +
                (index + 5) +
                '" class="preview"></div></div>'
              );
              $('#preview' + (index + 5)).attr('src', e.target.result);
            };
          }(index)) // Pass the current index as an arg, so its value is up-to-date
          reader3.readAsDataURL(file);
          console.log(index);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a helpful discussion about this issue in general: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

Comment: you save my day